# Statistical test for change in time series with one group

Tags: time-series, small-sample, latent-variable

I have conducted a latent class trajectory analysis using growth mixture models on a sample of 150 individuals. Individuals are assigned to 2 classes - 1 consisting of 18 individuals and the second 132. In testing predictor variables based upon the probability of being assigned to class 1 I have used some static time variables, but would also like to assess the potential associations with the change in said variable over time.

The predictor I would like to test consists of three observations for each individual over time. I would like to arrive at a change variable. The simplest approach would be to use the average raw or relative changes between the time points. However I would like to know if anyone has any advice about an appropriate statistical test to identify whether the change could be considered significant.

Any advice hugely appreciated